# htaccess and WordPress problems

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I wanna redirect all my wordpress pages from one domain to another, such as:

- from: `http://domain1.com/page/`
- to: `domain2.com/page/`

So I added to htaccess of domain1.com:
`RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain2.com\/$1 [R=301,L]`

But I want to make certain files exceptions to the above rule, so I also added:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(images|javascripts|stylesheets|css|images-globa|js-global|js|htm|html).*`

but the second rule doesn't seem to work. :(

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't exceptions, those are "the request **MUST** be images/javascripts/stylesheets/etc in order to redirect", so you've got it backwards. You want a `!` in there:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(images|javascripts|stylesheets|css|images-globa|js-global|js|htm|html)
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain2.com\/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Though I'm assuming you're way overreaching with the regular expression there, some of those look like you are matching against only the extension, so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(images|javascripts|stylesheets|css|images-globa|js-global)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|html?|png|je?pg|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain2.com\/$1 [R=301,L]
```